# How to trigger an action on a controller from a template

Tags: ember.js

I have this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ikihul/1#/nodes/index). My problem is that I am trying to trigger an `action`:

```
<a {{action controllers.nodesIndex.destroyAllRecords this}}><i class="icon-remove-circle"></i><a/>
```

But I get an:

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'controllers.nodesIndex.destroyAllRecords'
```

(You can trigger that by pressing the little icon `icon-remove-circle` on the top-right, and checking the error on the js console)

But my controller is properly set-up:

```
App.NodesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    destroyAllRecords: function () {
        console.log('destroyAllRecords called');
    },
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `<a {{action destroyAllRecords}}>...` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. Your comment worked, just *because* I had made a mistake putting together the jsbin. I have now updated the jsbin to show my real implementation: the change is that I am trying to trigger the action in the `nodes` template, not in the `nodes/index` template, because this is a common part for all nodes outlets. But from the `nodes` template neither `controllers.nodesIndex.destroyAllRecords` nor `destroyAllRecords` can be found. What can I do to trigger that method from the `nodes` template?

Comment: You've to put `needs: ['nodesIndex']` in yor `nodes` controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the controller for the `nodes/index` template is the `App.NodesIndexController`, You need to mention it as `controllers.nodesIndex.destroyAllRecords`, the default target will be `App.NodesIndexController`, and so you can just say `<a {{action destroyAllRecords}}>` as @Thomas told.

Also for getting the length of records, just say `{{this.length}}` instead of `{{controllers.nodesIndex.length}}`.

I've updated your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oqahej/2#/nodes/index),

You'll need to say as `'controllers.controllername.methodname'` only if you are referring to some other controller than the controller for the template, and you've to give the controller's name in the needs list,
say, if you want to call a method of your 'profile' route from your 'nodes/index' template,
then

```
App.NodesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['profile'],
});
```

and in your template,

```
<a {{action controllers.profile.methodname}}>
```

Hope it helps.

UPDATE: Refer the solution and the bin in the comment

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track. But if was not enough to define `needs`. I also needed to add to the `NodesController` the following: `destroyAllRecords: function () { var nodesIndexController = this.get('controllers.nodesIndex'); nodesIndexController.destroyAllRecords(); }` and then I can call `{{action destroyAllRecords}}` in the nodes template. Doing `{{action controllers.nodesIndex.destroyAllRecords}}` did not work, even after defining the `needs`. This looks complicated: I must define the `destroyAllRecords` twice. I wonder if there is a way to simplify this.

Comment: It shou;d've been `a {{action destroyAllRecords this target='controllers.nodesIndex'}}`, I've updated your [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ebagad/1#/nodes/index).
Under such scenarios you can simply define the action in your `nodesRoute` as the events of `nodesController`, `nodesIndexContrller` and events of all child routes of `nodesRoute` will bubble upto it, unless you need the event explicitly in `nodesIndexController`.